# Know who used a feature

Tags: javascript, security

i have a website with polls , i want the user to be able to vote one time only , i can't use use his IP address to know that he had voted before as the IP address all system users using is one (they are on LAN with one WAN ip address) . using the cookies is good , but what if he deleted the cookies to vote again ? , i don't want to use memberships also , or email verifications .

is there any way i could do it ? i don't know maybe know his mac address somehow :p .
what javascript can offer me (information about his PC) ?

thanky ou guys .

Comment: If you are using LAN and Windows AD then why not use membership user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about an ever cookie? http://samy.pl/evercookie/

Comment: Sorry but you should not promote evercookies. I would recommend he does not use this tool. Browsers are trying to protect against them - they are a security risk.

Comment: Absolutely no offence at all btw.

Answer (score 1):

You have pretty much described all of the options and trade-offs.  Unfortunately, unless you are planning to use a browser extension, plug-in, signed applet, elevated Silverlight client, or some other similar means, you can't get access to machine identifying data.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript will not allow you to know any of the PC details. Using Cookie is the way to go.